# Get value in hidden field, and display it in another page. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: php, hidden

This is a table of students' ID numbers, with a button after each ID.

When I click on a button, I want it to open a new page called "score.php", and display the selected ID.

But the code doesn't work. It only show the text "ID", but not the number.

Here is "index.php"

```html
<html>

    <head>test</head> 
  
    <body>  
  
        <form method="post" action="score.php">
 
            <?php 
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM term3_2556") 
             or die(mysql_error());      
 
             echo "<table border='1'>";
                 echo "<tr> <th>Student ID</th> </tr>";
                 
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                      echo "<tr>";
                   echo '<td>' . $row['student_id'] . '<input type="hidden" name="student_id" value=" ' .  $_POST['student_id'] . ' " /> <button type="submit" name="btn_student_id" >Select</button> </td> '; 
                            echo '</tr>';    
                     }  
          echo "</table>";

            ?> 
 
        </form>

    </body>  
  
</html>
```

And here is "score.php"

```
<head>test</head>

<body>

    <?php 

        $student_id = $_POST["student_id"];
        echo '<p> ID: '.$student_id.'</p>'; 

    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: When you hit submit, what is the new url that you get in the tab?

Comment: You have `n` number of `<input type="hidden" name="student_id"...`. So you need to specify which one you want.

Comment: The new URL is http://localhost/student/score.php

Comment: Thanks, but how do I specify the ID number I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a `<button>`, there is no need to use a `<input type="hidden">`. Just add the `student_id` as the button value -

```
<button type="submit" name="btn_student_id" value=" ' .  $row['student_id'] . ' " >Select</button>
```

Then in you php just get the value from the clicked on button -

```
<?php 

    $student_id = $_POST["btn_student_id"];
    echo '<p> ID: '.$student_id.'</p>'; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your index.php file will be:

```
    <html>

    <head>test</head> 

    <body>  

        <form method="post" action="score.php">

            <?php 
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM term3_2556") 
                or die(mysql_error());                  

                echo "<table border='1'>";
                    echo "<tr> <th>Student ID</th> </tr>";

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo '<td>' . $row['student_id'] . '<input type="hidden" name="student_id" value=" ' .  $row['student_id'] . ' " /> <button type="submit" name="btn_student_id" >Select</button> </td> '; 
                            echo '</tr>';               
                        }  
                echo "</table>";

            ?>  

        </form>

    </body>  

</html>
```